# File format not recognized when run ffmpeg example c program in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, ffmpeg, video-streaming, codeblocks

I am new to ffmpeg, currently I am testing the encodingd/decoding function of ffmepg. I open the [ffmeg/example/decoding_encoding.c](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decoding__encoding_8c-source.html) file in Codeblocks and linked relevant libs. But when build, it gives the error:

```
||=== Build: Debug in c_official_ffmepg (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|

ld cannot find ../../opencv-2.4.10/build/include: File format not recognized

||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

What cause this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might comes from a bad CodeBlocks configuration, your problem seems similar to this [post](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=6108.0):

> Right-click your header file,
>   select properties,
>   choose the Build tab,
>   and uncheck the "Compile file" and "Link file" options.
>
> Do this for each header file. You should only ever use the Compile option on a header if you specifically want it to be used as a precompiled header, and you should never use the Link option for a header.

Comment: Hi,ya the problem got solved, thanks. but some new problem pop out. lot of header file which include **"config.h"** shows error `fatal error: config.h No Such firl or directory.` What is the problem.

Comment: @Yoohoo If you have another problem you need to post another question

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it solved your pb. About the second one, the pb is ... `config.h` is missing or not found (check your includes). If it is an auto-generated file you probably missed a step during the build.